# Backtracking and combinatronics problem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, combinatorics, backtracking

So I've been trying to solve this problem and am kinda stuck at implementing it using backtracking and would really like to understand what I'm doing wrong here. I suspect my problem is something to do with arrays being passed by reference in the methods, but can't seem to put my finger on it. Any help is appreciated. This was asked in an interview and I am trying to solve it on my own.

Here is the question:

Cards have a suite and repeating time. Given a list of cards and output size, return a list with cards that have

(all same letter or all different letters) &
(all the same length or all different letter lengths).

```
exaple1:
input: ['X', 'Y', 'YY', 'ZZ', 'ZZZ'], 3
output: ['X', 'YY', 'ZZZ']

-------------

example2:
input: ['Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'ZZ', 'X', 'XX'], 3
output: ['Y', 'Z', 'X']

-------------

example3:
input: ['X', 'Y', 'YY', 'ZZ', 'ZZZ'], 3
output: ['X', 'YY', 'ZZZ']
```

My algorithm is as follows:

- call a helper method that returns if such a combo exists and the combo
- the helper method takes the list of cards and the number of cards in the output that's needed
- base case: return true and empty array if count is 0 (meaning we have no more cards to pick)
- iterate over each card
- find a combo for count - 1 cards with the current card being picked (recursively)
- if a combo is found, do checks with current card to make sure it can be added to the current combination and return
- if you've iterated over all cards and cannot find a combo, return false with empty array

```
  def unique_cards(cards, count)
    can, picked_cards = _unique_cards(cards, count)
    puts can ? picked_cards : false
  end

  def _unique_cards(cards, count)
    return [true, []] if count == 0
    cards.each do |card|
      card_length = card.length
      card_type = card[0]
      remaining_cards = cards - [card]
      can, selected_cards = _unique_cards(remaining_cards, count - 1)
      if can
        can_be_added = (selected_cards.all? { |c1| c1.length == card_length } || selected_cards.all? { |c1| c1[0] == card_type }) && (selected_cards.all? { |c1| c1.length != card_length   } || selected_cards.all? { |c1| c1[0] != card_type })
        if can_be_added
          selected_cards << card
          return [true, selected_cards]
        end
      end
    end
    return [false, []]
  end
```

Comment: "all same letter or all different letters & all the same length or all different letter lengths" is a bit vague for me, also could you add some more examples for input and output ?

Comment: On first glance I allready see an error, "puts can ? picked_cards : false" returns always nil, if you want to show the result and return the value use p instead of puts

Comment: I don't understand the puts vs p argument. I tried replacing with p and it's still the same. I've added a few more examples to make it clear. Basically we want to return n number of cards where the cards  (all same suite or all different suite) and (all same length or all different length).

Comment: "I suspect my problem is something to do with arrays being passed by reference in the methods" – Ruby is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference, so this *cannot possibly* be the problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I would say it's pass-by-value for the 40 bytes that define an object. If the object points to other data (cells of an array, characters in string, etc...) then you need to be careful.
d = [ 1, 2 ]; def f(a); a[0] = 0; end; f(d); d # => [0, 2]

Comment: It's a subtle difference, but I think Ruby is [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)

Comment: @streetsoldier i also find the description vague and would attempt this if it can be specified. it seems you are trying to define two behaviors but each example has only one output. why does example1 choose different lengths whereas example2 is different suits? what part of the _input_ is used to determine which result you will get?

Comment: It can pick either. Any result that satisfies the condition is acceptable. (All same suit or all different suit) and (all same size or all different size).

Comment: Initially I found the question confusing, but on careful reading I concluded you stated in precisely, which is refreshing when, as here, the requirement is somewhat complex.  Not so good are the typographical errors, one in the title itself.

Comment: Yeah. Couldn't come up with anything more precise in a succinct way. Either way, do you think you see the problem with my approach?

Comment: I would say this was a pretty tough interview question if you were expected to provide an answer on the spot. I think most experienced and capable Ruby coders, and probably the asker themself, would stumble, though all might well come up with good solutions in a few minutes when not under a microscope. My money is on the asker trying to out-tough the other interviewers, which is detrimental to the purpose of the interview.

Comment: I agree. This is a hard problem indeed. Especially when trying to solve it when someone is trying to judge your coding skills. To be fair, they allowed me to look up stuff on the internet. So there was that.

Comment: About the puts in your first method, try this: 
    `def a ; puts "a" end
    def b ; p "b" end
    p a # returns nil
    p b # returns b`
I'm not suggesting it's the cause of your problem, just consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'set'

def find_em(arr, n)
  arr.combination(n)
     .select do |a|
       [1, n].include?(a.map { |s| s[0] }.uniq.size) &&
       [1, n].include?(a.map(&:size).uniq.size)
      end.uniq(&:to_set)
end
```

```
find_em ['Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'ZZ', 'X', 'XX', 'Y'], 3
  #=> [["Y", "Y", "Y"], ["Y", "Z", "X"]]
find_em ['X', 'Y', 'YY', 'ZZ', 'ZZZ'], 3
  #=> [["X", "YY", "ZZZ"]]
find_em ['X', 'Y', 'YY', 'ZZ', 'ZZ'], 3
  #=> []
```

In the first example, without `.uniq(&:to_set)` we would obtain

```
find_em ['Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'ZZ', 'X', 'XX', 'Y'], 3
  #=> [["Y", "Y", "Y"], ["Y", "Z", "X"], ["Y", "Z", "X"], ["Z", "X", "Y"]]
```

See [Array#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) and [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

Comment: This solution definitely works and this is a very Ruby way of doing things. For larger sets, I imagine this will take a very long time. The space complexity especially is going to be big. We are going to be storing every possible combination of size n. I was looking for more of a backtracking sort of solution. More specifically I was looking for issues in my approach. I will accept this as an answer if I do not get anything better soon. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: But I must say I am really impressed with the solution you provided. Very clear what's happening here.

Comment: A few points: 1) for large arrays all methods will be time-consuming; 2) `Array#combination` without a block returns an enumerator, so the amount of memory required will depend on the size of array that is the receiver of `uniq(&:to_set)`; `Array#combination` is written in `C` so it will be much faster than using recursion to generate combinations; 4) at the expense of memory you could maintain a set of combinations already examined (saved as sets). For example, if you examined `["X", "Y", "Z"]`, you could save `#<Set: {"X", "Y", "Z"}>` to that set, allowing you to skip `["Y", "X", "Z"]`,...

Comment: ...for example, should it arise; 5) the proof of the pudding is in the eating, so let's see if there is a faster solution!

Comment: @Cary: if the "cards" represent a unique/physical item then it makes sense to keep the "duplicated" combinations.
Also, why did you use Array#select instead of Array#find ?

Comment: The choice between using `select` versus `find` depends on the meaning of the second appearance of the word `"list"` in "Given a list of cards and output size, return a list with cards that have...". I interpreted it to mean return all arrays of `n` cards that have the desired property. By all means use `find` if only one array of `n` cards is needed.

Comment: OK :-) In the case of returning the first list is fine, I wonder if using `arr.combination(n).lazy.find` would help speeding up things with large arrays

Comment: When using `find` `lazy` serves no purpose, since the search terminates when `find's` block returns `true`. If you were using `select`, and wanted the first, say, `m` matches, then the use of a `lazy` enumerator would be appropriate: `[*1..10].combination(3).lazy.select { |arr| arr.sum == 18 }.first(3) #=> [[1, 7, 10], [1, 8, 9], [2, 6, 10]]` (though this example is not directly applicable to the problem at hand).